# Does enabling JMX agent have a performance overhead?

Tags: java, performance, jmx

I would like to have a possibility to use jconsole in production, but am a bit concerned about performance. Is it ok to leave JMX agent running (via -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote) or will it have a noticeable performance footprint?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313730/is-a-good-idea-to-enable-jmx-lambda-probe-on-a-production-server

Comment: Thanks a lot, JoseK, this link contains all answers that I need!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is enabling JConsole remote monitoring affect system performance in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577758/is-enabling-jconsole-remote-monitoring-affect-system-performance-in-production)

Answer (score 19):

In general running the JVM with JMX enabled does not incur in appreciable performance hits.
The performance hit happens only when a tool like jconsole is connected and actually polling for information.

See the below link for more details:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20200820010106/https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2006/07/21/how-much-does-it-cost-monitor-app-jconsole

Comment: @tanderson Thanks for fixing the link. To make this answer even more time-proof I reccommend pasting the relevant parts of the linked article into this answer (OFC after verifying the license of the content).

Comment: That post is from 2006 and claims to be 'highly unscientific'. He says `Running with-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote has no appreciable impact. Connecting jconsole has an impact of 3--4%.' I'd like to see if the percentages for connecting jconsole holds for other tests but haven't found other references.

Answer (score 3):

From *Tuning Your GlassFish – Performance Tips* :

> **General Tuning Tips**
>
> Unused features could have a negative
>   impact on the performance and should
>   be disabled:
>
> - Auto-deployment of applications
> - **JMX Monitoring**
> - JMS
> - Dynamic JSP reloading
> - JDBC Connection validation
> - Security Manager could be turned off if the   applications are all
>     trusted internal applications

Source: http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/attach/GlassFishDay2008Hyderabad/GlassFishDay2008PerfPreso.pdf (PDF document)

Comment: yes, obviously turn off things you're not using, but if you're using JMX for monitoring, then likely it's worth the overhead.